# There is an item that is stuck in my inventory on a Minecraft server and if I destroy it, it just comes back!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am on the beanblockz server in crea build, and there are a bunch of enchanted boots stuck in my inventory. I can pick them up if I double click, and I can put them in destroy item, but then i put another item in the slot that they where in and it just changes back to the boots and that item is gone. And I can't contact the server because there is no 'help' option on the beanblockz website. I'm really annoyed. Can anyone help?

Comment: Does it only happen on this server?  Then chances are good they want you to have those boots, and we can't do anything to help.

Answer (score 3):

We can't really help with how server admins run their servers, so if they are forcing an item into your inventory, then you would have to talk to a server admin about it.